# Custom font in Android-listView makes scrolling laggy?

Tags: android, fonts, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a hundred items that scrolls fine.  I added one custom font to one of the `TextView`'s and now it is choppy.  I have tried both otf and ttf fonts.

Here is how  I have code (simplified):

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemObject> implements
        SectionIndexer {

private Typeface myTypeface; // class variable

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_layout, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        ItemObject io = getItem(position);
        String name = io.name;


        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/listitemfont.ttf");

        holder.t1.setText(name);
        holder.t1.setTypeface(myTypeface);


        return convertView;
    }
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating the same typeface *every* time `getView()` is called, move this line into your constructor:

```
myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/listitemfont.ttf");
```

And you probably don't need to re-set the typeface every time either, just when the TextView is created.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    ...
    holder.t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
    holder.t1.setTypeface(myTypeface); // Move this here
}
```

Comment: Ha, we did have the same thought and used almost the same description. I'll give Ralgha an upvote myself, this way he can outnumber me.

Comment: I gave you the edge because I also used your secondary tip.  Seems cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you're creating a new Typeface every time getView is called (which is a lot).  Try moving `myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/listitemfont.ttf");` into the constructor for your adapter.